# ~~ Assembly language shift left confirmation

Tags: assembly, bit-shift

I'm having trouble understanding "arithmetic shift left". I have the following instruction:

```
SAL   $0x2, edx
```

Where `edx = 0xFC`

```
0xFC = 1111 1100
```

By shifting left 2 we should have:

```
1111 0000 = 0xF0
```

Correct?

Comment: yes, probably with overflow flag set.

Comment: Um, `edx` is a 32-bit register, not an 8-bit register.

Comment: True, but the hex values are still correct, yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `edx` is a 32-bit register, and `edx = 0xFC` (equivalent to `edx = 11111100b`), arithmetic shift left would result in `1111110000b`, in other words, `edx = 0x3F0`